# A simple Java class for implementing code stop watches - follow-up

Tags: java, timer, benchmarking

I have received a nice answer for [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213244/a-simple-java-class-for-implementing-code-stop-watches) post. Now, it is my attempt for some improvement:

```
package net.coderodde.time;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class provides easy-to-use means for measuring elapsed time.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 12, 2019)
 */
public final class StopWatch {

    private boolean isMeasuring; // false by default.
    private long startTimeMillis;
    private long markTimeMillis;
    private final List<Long> memory = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Starts measuring time.
     */
    public void start() {
        setImpl(true);
    }

    /**
     * Stops measuring time.
     */
    public void stop() {
        setImpl(false);
    }   

    /**
     * Resets the starting time to the current moment.
     */
    public void reset() {
        setImpl(true);
    }

    private void setImpl(boolean expectedStatus) {
        if (expectedStatus) {
            checkMeasuringStatusIsOff();
        } else {
            checkMeasuringStatusIsOn();
        }

        startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        markTimeMillis  = startTimeMillis;
        isMeasuring     = !isMeasuring;
        memory.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Marks current time for future calculation of lap times.
     */
    public void mark() {
        checkMeasuringStatusIsOn();
        markTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the time elapsed from beginning of the current lap.
     * 
     * @return the lap time.
     */
    public long lap() {
        checkMeasuringStatusIsOn();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        memory.add(now);
        long saveMarkTimeMillis = markTimeMillis;
        markTimeMillis = now;
        return now - saveMarkTimeMillis;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the entire lap memory.
     * 
     * @return the list of lap times.
     */
    public long[] recall() {
        long[] mem = new long[memory.size()];
        mem[0] = memory.get(0) - startTimeMillis;

        for (int i = 1; i < mem.length; i++) {
            mem[i] = memory.get(i) -
                     memory.get(i - 1);
        }

        return mem;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the time of a full previous lap.
     * 
     * @return the lap time of the previous full lap.
     */
    public long split() {
        checkMeasuringStatusIsOn();

        switch (memory.size()) {
            case 1:
                return memory.get(0) - startTimeMillis;

            default:
                int index = memory.size() - 2;
                return memory.get(index + 1) - memory.get(index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "(isMeasuring=%b, startTimeMillis=%d, markTimeMillis=%d, " + 
                "memory=%s)",
                isMeasuring,
                startTimeMillis,
                markTimeMillis,
                memory.toString());
    }

    private void checkMeasuringStatus(boolean expecteedMeasuringStatus,
                                      String exceptionMessage) {
        if (isMeasuring != expecteedMeasuringStatus) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }

    private void checkMeasuringStatusIsOn() {
        checkMeasuringStatus(true, "The stopwatch is not ticking.");
    }

    private void checkMeasuringStatusIsOff() {
        checkMeasuringStatus(false, "The stopwatch is ticking.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(sw);
            String cmd = scanner.next();

            switch (cmd)  {
                case "start":
                    sw.start();
                    break;

                case "stop":
                    sw.stop();
                    break;

                case "recall":
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sw.recall()));
                    break;

                case "split":
                    System.out.println(sw.split());
                    break;

                case "lap":
                    System.out.println(sw.lap());
                    break;

                case "mark":
                   sw.mark();
                   break;

                case "quit":
                case "exit":
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, am I going into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: `expecteedMeasuringStatus` the word `expected` is spelled with only one consecutive `e`.

#### Measuring time:

Imagine that some user would start your application, start measuring the time, then **change the system time**, then at some point later stop the measuring. What happens? Your time measuring will be inaccurate. Solution: Use `System.nanoTime()` and not `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: True. Citing, _This method can only be used to measure elapsed time_